# Why Objective-C doesn't support method overloading?

Tags: objective-c, overloading

Objective-C doesn't support methods overloading.
Why?
Is it doable but Apple decided not implement it? or it is not doable due the dynamic nature of Objective-C?

I have the impression that method overloading can be done on compiled languages (Java, C#) and can't be done on interpreted languages (Ruby, Python).
Holds some true?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The distinction that's relevant here is not between compiled and interpreted languages, but between statically typed (Java, C#) and dynamically typed (Ruby, Python, Objective-C). In a dynamically typed language, type information is very often not known until runtime. At runtime, all objects are statically typed as `id` in Objective-C.

Additionally, a core idea in dynamically typed OO languages is that you should not care what type an object is as long as it responds to the messages you want to send. So overloading based on type would fly right in the face of that.

Comment: hypothetically, is it possible to have a dynamically typed language that supports method overloading? does such a language exist now?

Comment: Hypothetically? Sure;  it could even be done on top of Objective-C today, if you wanted to go there (and if you wanted to completely depart from existing coding standards).  It really wouldn't even be "that hard" (for some values of "hard", anyway).

Comment: I am afraid Chuck, I didn't understand your answer. Can you please explain what you are trying to say.

Comment: @Nitish: I'm not sure how to say it too much more clearly than I did here. Overloading a method means having several different methods with the same name but different types. Objective-C doesn't require types to be known ahead of time (and very often they will not be) and instead relies on objects to respond to the right messages for the places where they're used. This is philosophically incompatible with overloading. Objective-C just does it a different way.