# Why does objective C does not support overloading?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, overloading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why Objective-C doesn't support method overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444783/why-objective-c-doesnt-support-method-overloading)

I was going through [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444783/why-objective-c-doesnt-support-method-overloading) which has the answer to my question. But I was not able to understand what the right guy is trying to say. It will be really great if someone can simplify and provide an explanation.

Comment: Maybe you could use the comment feature and approach "the right guy" over on that thread?

Comment: Maybe you are right. But maybe you can provide an explanation :)

Comment: So can Chuck - he was "last seen 2 hours ago".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ the compiler has type information and can choose between several methods based on the types. To do the same in Objective C it would have to be done at run-time, because the compiler knows little about object types due to the dynamic nature of the language (i.e. all objects are of type `id`). While this seems possible, it would be very inefficient in practice.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a historical artifact.  Objective-C is derived from C and Smalltalk, and neither of them support overloading.

If you want overloading, you can use Objective-C++ instead.  Just name your sources with the ".mm" extension instead of just ".m".

Just be careful to be sure you know what you are doing if you mix C++ and Objective-C idioms.  For example Objective-C exceptions and C++ exceptions are two completely different animals and cannot be used interchangeable.

Comment: I guess I understand what you are saying. I have used .mm extension before when I was working on IPhone game development in Box2D.

Answer (score 1):

What he is trying to say is that method overloading is not possible with dynamic typed languages since in dynamic typed languages the information about each of the object is not known until run time. In a statically typed during compile time the overloading can be resolved. You will just create the same functions with same names but the compiler would have enough information to resolve the ambiguity between various calls which it gets. But in dynamic typed languages since the objects are resolved only during run time it is not possible to resolve between the various calls.

Comment: Operator overloading can be a source of unnecessary copies and constructors, some of which modern compilers can avoid. It's these optimisations that are not possible in a dynamic type language. Enough reason to steer clear of it, after all it's just a syntax thing.

Comment: @Kris: a) All the claimed "operator overloading abuse" can easily be transformed into "function abuse", b) was your intention really to comment on swordfishs answer?

Comment: a) With a regular syntax at least you are aware of calling a function and passing arguments. b) I wanted to reject the statement: not possible because of dynamic type language by stating that only the optimizations are not possible.